# DialogFlow simulator operates differently from the web integration

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to develop an agent using DialogFlow. When doing this, it is possible to debug the agent via the link https://console.dialogflow.com/api-client/#/assistant_preview .This (sort of) works as far as it allows me to interact with my agent etc. On the DialogFlow integrations page I can create a "Web Demo". Typing in exactly the same interactions with the web demo when trying to perform user sign in fails, where as on the simulator it works.

This may be similar to [Dialogflow Agent works in Google simulator, failed in console and web link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51112543/dialogflow-agent-works-in-google-simulator-failed-in-console-and-web-link)

Surely both methods of interaction should work the same way otherwise this is impossible to test with any level of confidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User sign-in is an Assistant feature that Dialogflow supports, but it is not a Dialogflow feature.

The Web Demo is just that - a demo. You can use the Dialogflow [Detect Intent API](https://dialogflow.com/docs/sdks#detect_intent_and_agent_apis) and provide your own authentication system through that if that's what you're trying to do.

If you're looking to test just the Dialogflow interaction, you can test that using the [simulator](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents/test) on the right hand side of the page.